# update data.table based on last change in another data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I currently have two data tables that look like the following:

```
dt1 <- data.table(urn=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2"),
                  date=as.Date(c("2014-01-15","2014-02-15","2014-03-15","2014-04-15","2014-05-15","2014-06-15","2014-07-15",
                         "2014-04-15","2014-05-15","2014-06-15","2014-07-15",
                         "2014-04-15","2014-03-15","2014-05-15","2014-02-15","2014-06-14","2014-08-15","2014-07-15","2014-09-16")),
                  amount=c(20,20,15,15,15,20,25,
                           15,15,20,20,
                           30,30,30,30,25,25,25,20))

#dt1
#    urn       date amount
# 1:   1 2014-01-15     20
# 2:   1 2014-02-15     20
# 3:   1 2014-03-15     15
# 4:   1 2014-04-15     15
# 5:   1 2014-05-15     15
# 6:   1 2014-06-15     20
# 7:   1 2014-07-15     25
# 8:   2 2014-04-15     15
# 9:   2 2014-05-15     15
#10:   2 2014-06-15     20
#11:   2 2014-07-15     20
#12:   3 2014-04-15     30
#13:   3 2014-03-15     30
#14:   3 2014-05-15     30
#15:   3 2014-02-15     30
#16:   3 2014-06-14     25
#17:   3 2014-08-15     25
#18:   3 2014-07-15     25
#19:   2 2014-09-16     20

dt2 <- data.table(urn=c("1","2","3"), lastamount=c(25,20,25),lastchangedate=as.Date(c(NA,NA,NA)))

#dt2
#    urn lastamount lastchangedate
# 1:   1         25           <NA>
# 2:   2         20           <NA>
# 3:   3         25           <NA>
```

A couple of important things to note, (1) The urn isn't always ordered, (2) the date isn't always correctly ordered, (3) the amount may go up or down and (4) the date may skip a month, and (5) the date isn't always the same day of the month.

What I am trying to achieve is a way to update dt2 lastchangedate to reflect the most recent date that the amount was changed (either increased, or decreased).

So I would expect dt2 to look like the following after processing.

```
#dt2
#    urn lastamount lastchangedate
# 1:   1         25     2014-07-15
# 2:   2         20     2014-06-15
# 3:   3         25     2014-06-14
```

This is obviously a sample data set. To give an order of magnitude my real dt1 has 3.5M records and dt2 has 250K records.

Thanks

UPDATE:
As my real dt2 has more columns than just those shown in the sample, I need to be able to keep them in my final output. Rather than overwrite the current instance of dt2 I wanted to just update the lastchangedate in isolation. Below is the code I used.

```
setkey(dt1, urn) # this is after I had used setkey(dt1, urn, date) to order dt1 properly
setkey(dt2, urn)

dt2[dt1[,list(lastchangedate=max(date[which(diff(amount)!=0)+1])), 
    by=urn],lastchangedate:=i.lastchangedate]
```

Comment: Being fairly new to stackoverflow I am trying to understand how to ask helpful questions. I'd really appreciate the feedback on what about this question was unhelpful so I can improve for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
setkey(dt1, urn, date)   ## sort table
dt2 <- dt1[, list(lastamount=amount[.N],
                  lastchangedate=max(date[which(diff(amount)!=0)+1])), 
           by=urn]
```

The last line looks at where `diff(amount) != 0` and offsets it by one (index of rows where a change occurs) and returns the latest date (`max`).